# Keep getting StopIteration in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

I am using the following code of Pytorch to generate Dataset class:

```
class BlockSet(Dataset):
   def __init__(self, imList, mkList): #, transform=None):
     self.imList = imList
     self.mkList = mkList
     # self.transform = transform

   def __len__(self):
     return len(self.imList)

   def __getitem__(self, index):
     im = Image.open(self.imList[index]).convert('RGB')
     mk = Image.open(self.mkList[index]).convert('L')
     im = np.array(im)
     mk = np.array(mk)
     return im, mk
```

When I try to take a unit sample for test with:

```
unitSet = BlockSet(refFiles, mskFiles)
x,y = next(iter(unitSet))
```

I get `StopIteration` error in jupyter notebook. But when I run it in some .py script using pycharm it runs and give me expected results.

What's wrong with .ipynb files?

Comment: I'd expect that exception to mean an empty input list, so I'd check that `refFiles` contains what you expect before you pass it to `BlockSet`.

Comment: I am running the same codes so things should be the same. `refFiles` is a list of absolute paths to the images.

Comment: Sure. I'm just suggesting that your issue is not likely to be in the code you've shown. It's probably somewhere up above the `unitSet = BlockSet(...)` line, and we can't possibly guess what it is. You can test to verify if `refFiles` is empty by printing it (or its `len`).

Comment: Yes, I have checked that too. `len(refFiles)` shows `294` the same number of images in the directory.